# How to read in matrices from a text file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text

So I have a text file containing matrices and vectors on each line in the following format:
A = [0 1 0 ... 0];
B = [0 1 0 ... 0];
.
.
.
How can I read in these values and create the same vectors and matrices?

I have used the following approach but the vectors are empty once created.

```
fo = fopen('filename.txt', 'r');

A = fscanf(fo, '%f', [m n]);
```

Comment: It looks like you have a MATLAB script. If the file name ends in `.m`, you can run it like any command, just type the name of the file without the `.m` at the MATLAB command prompt or in your script.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this didn't work for me due to all of the matrices being read into one.

Comment: Then you need to show the actual file, your description makes it look like that would work.

Comment: if all the matrices are being read into one ( let's say M) , an easy fix is: `A = M(1,:); B=M(2,:);` etc